# What does Javascript: void%200 actually do?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to find what `<a href="javascript:void%200;">` does. I didn't find anything useful in google. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: The %20 is the uri escape for a space, it's really `javascript:void 0`. Googling that should get you there.

Comment: @JaredSmith Is %200 the same?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand exactly what you mean by "the same". If you run " 0" through e.g. `encodeURIComponent` you get back "%200" because spaces aren't valid URI characters.

Comment: @Giannis No. the `%20` is the url-encoded character for space. The second zero is a literal `0` in the string. It's valid in a URL already and doesn't need encoding.

Comment: @ADyson Oh, I thought is was %200. Thank you for the clarification.